# Jump To Parent's Bracket in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

This is Visual Studio Code question regarding shortcut. I know I can jump between match tag using `CTRL+SHIFT+{`

But how to jump from bracket (from here) to bracket (to here)? I mean go to closest parent's bracket. Possible?

```
a: { //to here
    b: {
    
    },
    c: function() { //not here
    
    }, //from here
}
```

Alternatively if not possible, any shortcut to close all siblings bracket? So that I can quickly know the parent? Or get the parent's info (eg function name or line number)

Answer (score 10):

I post same question at many places. So 1 of them came back with solution.

Open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), select "Go To Parent Fold".