# How to jump to parent's bracket in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

```js
function outerFunction() { // 3

    function innerFunction() { // 2

        // 1

    }
}
```

My cursor is currently at position `1`. After I use this keyboard shortcut, the cursor should now be at position `2`. After I press the same shortcut again, the cursor should be at position `3`.

There is a [similar keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72402519/jump-to-parents-bracket-in-visual-studio-code) in Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut command is called `Move Caret to Code Block End/Start`

On Mac:

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> ... Move Caret to Code Block Start

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> ... Move Caret to Code Block End

On Windows:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> ... Move Caret to Code Block Start

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> ... Move Caret to Code Block End

To edit the keymap:

Keymap > Editor Actions > Move Caret to Code Block End/Start